# WP8 : IExplorer 10 : on "keyup" event not firing for "RETURN" key

Tags: windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10, onkeyup

I've just came across this interesting problem, or probably it's just me missing something very basic (hopefully). The problem is, that the `keyup` event is not firing for the `return` key in the WP8 browser, whereas all the other standard keys are firing this event up.
I've tested this on the desktop, and IE10 is not having any issues with this, the event fires up nicely.

Can anyone else confirm that on their WP8 devices the `keyup` event is not being triggered for the "return" key ?

```
/using dojo syntax here/

 on(dom.byId("testinput1"), "keyup", function(evt){
    dom.byId("result1").innerHTML = "";
     if (evt.keyCode == keys.ENTER)
         dom.byId("result1").innerHTML = "ENTER pressed.";
});
```

Here is the [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/YFUCE/7/) link

- open it in IE10 -> no problem for both of the input boxes
- open it in WP8 browser (IE10) -> the first input box wont trigger `keyup` for the `return` key

Thanks for all your help.

Comment: There is an item on [Microsoft's site](http://connect.microsoft.com/IE/feedback/details/805619/windows-phone-ie10-ignoring-keyup-on-enter-key) but as of today it is active and without workarounds. If you are looking for a workaround, the `keydown` and  `keypress` events will fire for the enter key. So you could look for the enter key on one of those events. Check [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/q98Qq/)

Comment: I've posted that question on MS site in hope they would fix it. I just hate "work-arounding" the lack of implementation for IE no matter what version. Thanks for the input, I've already managed to do that in the same way you have suggested.