# WP8 : IE10 : Differences : Unexpected click through on WP8

Tags: javascript, html, windows-phone-8, internet-explorer-10

I've came across another difference in implementation of IE10 on Windows 8 and Windows Phone 8 (WP8). The first one was related to the IE10 being deaf/blind to `keyup` event of "enter". Read more [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19027624/wp8-iexplorer-10-on-keyup-event-not-firing-for-return-key)

The other problem I'm facing now is the `click` event being triggered even if it's not supposed to be triggered. Again, in Windows 8, it works as expected. In WP8, clicking on the top element (link -> [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ4dG/4/)) triggers the `onclick` event of the element at the bottom, even if they are not nested within each other (both have `body` element as a parent).

To test,

- open the following [jsfiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ4dG/4/) in IE10 on your desktop, and click the `element 2`, the one on top. The expected result is that nothing will happen.
- open the same link in IE10 in your WP8 handheld, and click the same element. The `onclick` event is triggered on `element 1`, which is not expected.

Could please anyone shed some more light into this for me?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a bizarre behavior. However there is a pretty simple solution for this.

```
  var modal = document.getElementById("elem2");
  modal.onclick = function(e) { 
      return false;
  }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/jQ4dG/20/)